# Instructions on third party framework dependency in building own framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I am working on an iOS framework, I need to have some guidelines on third party framework dependencies.

Suppose I need to use some open source framework(e.g.: AFNetworking) to build my own framework and my framework will be used by some partner applications who also using the same AFNetworking in their main project. Or their app is using another library/framework that is also using AFNetworking.

So my intension is to avoid integrating that AFNetworking into my framework and asked to partner to do that by their own through proper guidelines, I mean with documentation.

So what should I don in my app side as well as the process that partner app should follow. Actually to clarify the dependencies.

Any on hand tutorial will be great. Thank you :)